# polymorphic_on-column not filled out in sqlalchemy during insert

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I have a hierarchy and model definition like so:

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"

    company_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_name = Column(Text)
    employees = relationship("Employee")


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee"

    employee_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("company.company_id"))
    position = Column(Text)

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": position, 'polymorphic_identity':'employee'}


class Manager(Employee, ConcreteBase):
    __tablename__ = "manager"

    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("employee.employee_id"), primary_key=True)
    fancy_title = Column(Text)

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "Manager"}
```

And I then insert a `Manager` like so:

```
ceo = Manager(fancy_title="CEO")
big_inc = Company(company_name="Big Inc.", employees=[ceo])
session.add(big_inc)
session.commit()
```

When I look in the `Employee`-table, the `position` field is not filled out. **Why?**

```
companydb=# SELECT * FROM employee;
 employee_id | company_id | position 
-------------+------------+----------
           1 |          1 | 
(1 row)
```

I expected it to say:

```
companydb=# SELECT * FROM employee;
 employee_id | company_id | position 
-------------+------------+----------
           1 |          1 | Manager
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question like so many times before:

```
class Manager(Employee, ConcreteBase):
```

should not have `ConcreteBase` in it

```
class Manager(Employee):
```

Obviously because it does not make any sense to have this on the child…